# What do the different types of BufferedImage mean?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

The documentation of BufferedImage is pretty ... terse.

What do the different types mean? What do I get back when I call getPixel() for `TYPE_INT_ARGB`? How is it different from what I get back when the type is `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`? What about the other types?

Answer (score 2):

TYPE_INT_ARGB uses Integer to save a color of pixel, like

```
int color = 0xAARRGGBB,
```

but 3BYTE_BGR uses

```
byte[] color = new byte[Blue, Green, Red]
```

I recommend uses INT_ARGB, you can use alpha, in 3BYTE there are not channel alpha. Integer is faster, than array of byte and easy, for example to get any color use:

```
(COLOR >> 16) & 0xFF; (24-16 bits are RED).
(COLOR >>  8) & 0xFF; (16- 8 bits are GREEN).
(COLOR >>  0) & 0xFF; ( 8- 0 bits are BLUE).
```

I always use INT_ARGB or INT_RGB (if I don't need alpha)

Comment: How do you know this? What about the other types?

Comment: Also, `getPixel()` returns an `int[]` array. How does that work with `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`? Does `getPixel()` map the values or do I get one `int` per `byte`?

Answer (score 2):

Type represents pixel color type.

Like TYPE_INT_ARGB uses 8 bits for ALPHA component, 8 bits for RED component, 8 bits for GREEN component and 8 bits for BLUE component of color. So pixel color can be stored in `int` value.

TYPE_3BYTE_BGR do not store ALPHA component of color. It uses only 3 bytes of `int` value.

Like TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB uses 5 bits for each RED, GREEN and BLUE component of color. As it uses 5 bits only, it will have limited number of colors than TYPE_INT_ARGB or TYPE_3BYTE_BGR.

ALPHA component represents how image is transparent.

Likewise other types defines different color schemes.